# How do I query SQLite Database using changing variables?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Running SQLite on Python I am probably not phrasing this correctly but, instead of the code below:

```
c.execute("SELECT date, name FROM Results WHERE ID=? ",([id]))
```

Returns

```
Jane Doe
```

I am looking to do something like this:

```
queryVari='Name'

c.execute("SELECT date, ? FROM Results WHERE ID=? ",([queryVari,id]))
```

Currently returns

```
Name
```

instead of `Jane Doe`

The problem is that the query will depend on the user input and will likely never be quite the same. Is this possible?

Comment: No.  You can't bind database objects this way. Your only choice is to concatenate database object (column in this case) to your sql string, which, of course, introduces a sql injection attack vector.... so make sure that thing is as sanitized as possible before you concatenate it in. Or don't do this at all and bring back every column and choose the one you want after it's retrieved.

Comment: Ok thanks! That what I was afraid of.

Comment: Sorry the news isn't better. Ultimately what's happening under the hood is that the database gets that sql string as-is and it prepares the execution path to retrieve the data without knowing what the literals are. Then it gets the literals and it executes. It can't determine the execution path if it doesn't know the objects (columns may be indexed or partitioned or what-have-you).

Answer (score 0):

You can't substitute table and column names using the ? substitution, because that supplies quotes that turn the names into literals, but you can do it with string functions::

```
queryVari='Name'
c.execute(f"SELECT date, {queryVari} FROM Results WHERE ID=? ",([id]))
```